# What is the difference to the international version of the Twin Peaks pilot and why is there a difference?

Tags: alternate-version, twin-peaks

I decided to start watching "Twin Peaks". But it has two pilot episodes, one of them an alleged "international version" that is 20 minutes longer than the other.

What are the differences between those two pilot episodes? What is missing from the non-international version and why is there such a significant difference in running length?

Answer (score 6):

This is all covered on [**Wikipedia**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilot_(Twin_Peaks)#Home_video_release) under "Home video release"

> Due to rights issues, the American pilot (94 minutes long) was not released in the United States home video market until 2007. The European pilot (116 minutes) had been released on VHS and laser disc years earlier: this alternate version of the pilot was aired in Europe as a stand-alone television movie. **The European version is identical to the United States-aired version up until the last several scenes, when the killer of Laura Palmer is revealed.** Both versions of the pilot are included in the Twin Peaks: Definitive Gold Box Edition DVD set, released in the US on 30 October 2007.[24] **Lynch was so pleased with the footage shot for the European ending that he later incorporated some of it into Cooper's dream sequences that aired in subsequent episodes.**